# CSS not showing when page is redirected

Tags: css, asp.net, master-pages

Asp.net site css shows if i login but once i logout using the LoginStatus control the css and the banner for the page does not show. If i try to go directly to a page without logging in it redirects to login page but no css and banner.

I use the complete address in the master page for the css and the banner but it still doesnt show.

I am using roles. Below is a section of my web.config

```
<authorization>
     <deny users="?" />
     <allow roles="user" />
   </authorization>
   <roleManager enabled="true" />
   <authentication mode="Forms" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add your CSS path as allowed path for all users:

```
<location path="CSSFolderPath">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```